# Performance Issues using SQL Server Reporting Services in SharePoint Integrated Mode

Tags: integrated-mode, reporting-services, performance

Does anyone have experience with the following issue?  Are there any known workarounds?

Official MS Statement: General overhead performance differences when you view reports in SharePoint integrated mode versus in SharePoint native mode: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2216504

Further info:

http://sqlcat.com/technicalnotes/archive/2010/11/03/reporting-services-performance-in-sharepoint-integrated-mode-in-sql-server-2008-r2.aspx

> Furthermore, the performance of
>   individual reports viewed using the
>   ASP.NET Ajax-enabled Report Viewer web
>   part in SharePoint 2010 degrades
>   significantly when there are multiple
>   viewers on a single web page, the
>   viewer generates very large HTML, and
>   the web page is viewed using older
>   browsers.

http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-bloggers/what%E2%80%99s-up-with-the-slow-ssrs-r2-rendering-in-sharepoint-2010-integrated-mode/

> “This performance problem seems to be
>   particularly noticeable on pages with
>   a larger number of valid values in a
>   parameter, a large report page, or
>   multiple viewers (or web parts) on a
>   single page“

Comment: This question has been closed due to the site policy [described here](http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121/when-should-we-allow-questions-about-products-that-dont-belong-to-a-sharepoint-s/130#130). Please add any comments you have about the closure to that topic.

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to look at the structure of your pages. Consider what information your user requires on each page. If some information is almost never used place it on a separate page.

That way you will be able to give the users most information they need reasonably quickly, while requiring an extra request for information that is not used as often.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that an SSRS report will repeatedly make calls back to the report server, even if it's a report that contains no data.  This can cause problems if you have a report on the front page of your portal, as users may tend to keep that page open, causing massive hits on your report server.  Brought down our portal in the first couple of hours on a Monday morning with ~4000 users.  Took the report off the front page and everything went back to normal.